# Assuming fair use - where do I legally get video content?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

This question is in relation to US law.

Example:
*I'm making a youtube video that will be commercialized. Assume it falls under fair use; it will contain small clips from several different movies but will mostly consist of original content*

Again, please assume this falls under Fair Use.

**How do I legally obtain the video clips for use in my project? Can I rip them from a DVD? Can I torrent them (while owning a physical copy)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this falls under fair use, you can use your DVDs. The problem with torrents is that you get in the swarm and are now sharing and distributing copyrighted content, so you want to avoid that.